# Edge, Chrome and Brave react differently on <marquee behavior="slide" ..../> than expected

Tags: html, cross-browser, marquee

Edge, Chrome and Brave react differently on `<marquee behavior="slide" ..../>` than expected. I have a page that shows panorama photos.

If these photos are wider than the window then `behavior="scroll"` is used the photo will appear on the right and if the photo on the left disappears it will reappear on the right.

If photos are smaller then `behavior="slide"` is used and the photo enters the frame from the right and the photo stops scrolling when the left side of the photo reaches the left part of the window. This is also described in the description of "Slide" in the various behaviors at Marquee.

In Firefox this also works according to this description. However, it appears that in Edge and in Brave this does not work, the photo disappears just like with "scroll" to the left of the screen and then appears to stop instead of remaining on the screen in its entirety.

Does anyone have an idea what to do about this, besides making an exception that if Edge or Brave is used "scroll" instead of "slide" is also used as behavior?

Link with slide: https://davidbrouwer.nl/PanoramaHsvg.php?land=BoliviaPeru&foto=BoliviaChiliPan0031&taal=NL&direction=left&speed=2

Link with scroll: https://davidbrouwer.nl/PanoramaHsvg.php?land=BoliviaPeru&foto=BoliviaPeruPanorama01&taal=NL&direction=left&speed=2

In both options the checkbox also has a function, with which you can show texts on the photo (with option two it only appears at the very end) and that is the reason I am renovating this page.

PS: This is still a test page if you use the menu at the bottom you will get in the old version in a new window.

Comment: Just a few things I noticed:
**1**. You seem to be using the screen's width and not the browser's. If I reduce the browser's window, the first image should be in scroll mode, but it's still in slide mode. Also at the top I still see my screen's width right at the left of the picture's size. I wonder if tiny differences in pixel widths across browsers are what causes the difference in behavior.
**2**. The speed scroll doesn't work in the first link, probably because of the "slide" attribute. Shouldn't it? And in the scroll case, it's applied only to the following image passing.
(continues)

Comment: **3**. Firefox works as you described, although the movement is not smooth, and the slider affects the speed in the scroll case in realtime.
**4**. Opera and Vivaldi also behave like Edge.